# Grafana: how to use variable in sql query

Tags: grafana

How I can use variable in sql query at Grafana?
I have variable `robot` but I do not know how I can use it in sql query.
My query:

```sql
SELECT 
  datetime AS "time",
  api_robot.name AS "robot name",
  api_task.name AS "task name",
  api_status.name AS "task status"
FROM api_robotlog, api_robot, api_status, api_task
WHERE 
    -- api_robot.name = {$robot}
   api_robotlog.robot_id = api_robot.id
  AND api_robotlog.task_id = api_task.id
```

I try add some clauses at WHERE like:
`api_robot.name = {$robot}`
`api_robot.name = ${robot}`
But when I use it, I do not receive any data. Any idea?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Grafana variable syntax, which will generate correct SQL condition, e.g.:

```
api_robot.name = $robot
```

You may also need [advance variable format options](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/advanced-variable-format-options/), e.g.:

```
api_robot.name = '${robot:raw}'
```

Comment: thank You! 2nd case (with {} and '') working!